# Find out what's going to be deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

When using more complex, hierarchical models with differing settings on how cascade deletes are handled it gets quite hard to figure out beforehand what a `delete()` will exactly do with the database.

I couldn't find any way to get this piece of information ("*Hey SQLAlchemy, what will be deleted if I delete that object over there?*") from SQLAlchemy. Implementing this by myself doesn't really seem like an option since this would result sooner or later in situations where my prediction and the actual consequences of the `delete()` differ, which would be very… unpleasant for the user.

Comment: Why do you need to know? If you've designed your schema properly, the cascaded deletes will "do the right thing" -- deleting a user will delete all rows associated with that user. Maybe what you really want is a "deleted" column that you set to true instead of actually removing data?

Comment: @dom0 I think `session.deleted` and setting `session.autoflush=False` should let you inspect which objects will be deleted before you commit.

Comment: @Seth OP wasn't questioning whether the ORM would do the right thing, they wanted to know *what* was going to be deleted. And knowing what is going to be deleted is INCREDIBLY useful (I can't imagine why you don't think so).

Comment: @Colleen - do you have an example? Seriously, I am pretty sure I've never wanted to know what was going to be deleted _after_ I called `DELETE FROM (...)`. The only example I can think of is logging, but presumably the DBMS would do that.

Comment: @Seth..... did you read the question? "it gets quite hard to figure out beforehand" BEFOREHAND.

Comment: The trick that Michael also mentioned in his answer is, that with SQLAlchemy the DBMS isn't used to create the delete casace, but rather SQLAlchemys own implementation. This way you can delete your object read Session.deleted and **roll the delete back**. The latter part is the important thing that Seth probably forgot to mention :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on the SQLAlchemy mailing list to
and [Michael Bayer explained the possible options](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sqlalchemy/H4nQTHphc0M/Xr8-Cgra0Z4J) (thanks a lot again! :-):

> The only deletes that aren't present in session.deleted before the flush are those that will occur because a particular object is an "orphan", and the objects which would be deleted as a result of a cascade on that orphan.
>
> So without orphans taken into account, session.deleted tells you everything that is to be deleted.
>
> To take orphans into account requires traversing through all the relationships as the unit of work does, looking for objects that are currently orphans (there's an API function that will tell you this - if the object is considered an "orphan" by any attribute that refers to it with delete-orphan cascade, it's considered an "orphan"), and then traversing through the relationships of those orphans, considering them to be marked as "deleted", and then doing all the rules again for those newly-deleted objects.
>
> The system right now is implemented by orm/dependency.py.   It is probably not hard to literally run a unit of work process across the session normally, but just not emit the SQL, this would give you the final flush plan.   But this is an expensive process that I wouldn't want to be calling all the time.
>
> A feature add is difficult here because the use case is not clear.    Knowing what will be deleted basically requires half the flush process actually proceed.   But you can already implement events inside the flush process itself, most directly the before_delete() and after_delete() events that will guaranteed catch everything.    So the rationale for a new feature that basically runs half the flush, before you just do the flush anyway and could just put events inside of it, isn't clear.
>
> I guess the big question is, "when are you calling this".
>
> An easy system would be to add a new event "flush_plan_complete" which will put you into a flush() right as the full plan has been assembled, but before any SQL occurs.   It could allow you to register more objects for activity, and it would then rerun the flush plan to consider any new changes (since that's how it works right now anyway).  How this registration would proceed is tricky, since it would be nice to use the Session normally there, but that makes this more complicated to implement.   But then it could iterate again through the new changes and find any remaining steps to take before proceeding normally.